# javascript animation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

i already let you know that i am not good in speaking english :S. if i make wrong sentences then you know why.

I have made a script where i can type the color, height and width. if you click on the submit you will see the result on the screen.

i am trying to animate the result with setInterval. i want to see the movement of the result.

i hope you know what i mean..

My script:

```
function button(){  
            var width = 0;
            var height = 0;


            var color= document.getElementById("color").value;
            var lengte = document.getElementById("lang").value + 'px';
            var breedte = document.getElementById("breed").value + 'px';

            width++

            document.getElementById("result").style.backgroundColor = color;
            document.getElementById("result").style.width = breedte;
            document.getElementById("result").style.height = lengte;

            if(width == breedte){
                clearInvent(id)
            }
            var id = setInterval(button);
        }
        function maakEvent(){
            document.getElementById("button").onclick = button;
        }
        window.onload = maakEvent;
```

my HTML:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>What color do you want to show?</td><td><input type="text" id="color"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>How long must it be?</td><td><input type="text" id="lang"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>how wide should it be?</td><td><input type="text" id="breed"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="show" id="button"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

the words: lengte/lang and breedte/breed are dutch words. it means length and width. they are dutch becuase i speak dutch.

what have i done wrong?

Comment: Just a suggestion: I would use jQuery for animation.

Comment: To start, usually each command ends with ; So add a semicolon on  
            width++;    and  clearInvent(id);

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestion from drive235 you should use jquery, but without this also you can achieve the result. But you issue with SetInterval syntax:

```
SetInterval(function(){ }, <interval in millisecond>);
```

You should write:

```
 var id = setInterval(function() {button()}, 30000);
```

Another issue is with the values you are assigning:

```
 document.getElementById("result").style.width = breedte;
```

You are assigning the final width in first iteration itself, so it would be same everytime and no effect will be visible.

Your code should be:

```
document.getElementById("result").style.width = width;
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the complete code, which works on Chrome (at least):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   var id;
   var width = 0;
    function test(){
     id = setInterval(function(){ button()},1000);
     }
    function button(){  

        var height = 0;


        var color= document.getElementById("color").value;
        var lengte = document.getElementById("lang").value + 'px';
        var breedte = document.getElementById("breed").value + 'px';

        width+=10;

        document.getElementById("result").style.backgroundColor = color;
        document.getElementById("result").style.width = width
        document.getElementById("result").style.height = lengte;

        if(width == breedte){
            clearInvent(id)
        }

    }
    function maakEvent(){
        document.getElementById("button").onclick = test;
    }
    window.onload = maakEvent;
```

Comment: i don't see the result growing. it comes in all sudden on the screen without a bit effect.